# Display two messages at the same time with SwiftMessages pod

Tags: ios, swift

I'm using the SwiftMessages pod to display messages in my app.
(https://github.com/SwiftKickMobile/SwiftMessages)

I would like to display two messages at the same time, by example, one at the top, one at the bottom.

In the Readme, it's written:

> Multiple instances of SwiftMessages can be used to show more than one
>   message at a time. Note that the static SwiftMessages.show() and other
>   static APIs on SwiftMessage are just convenience wrappers around the
>   shared instance SwiftMessages.sharedInstance):
>
> let otherMessages = SwiftMessages()
>
> SwiftMessages.show(...)
>
> otherMessages.show(...)

So, I taken some of the demo code and I tried with multiple instances:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    let error = MessageView.viewFromNib(layout: .TabView)
    error.configureTheme(.error)
    error.configureContent(title: "Error", body: "Something is horribly wrong!")
    error.button?.setTitle("Stop", for: .normal)

    let status2 = MessageView.viewFromNib(layout: .StatusLine)
    status2.backgroundView.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange
    status2.bodyLabel?.textColor = UIColor.white
    status2.configureContent(body: "Hello")
    var status2Config = SwiftMessages.defaultConfig
    status2Config.presentationContext = .window(windowLevel: UIWindowLevelNormal)
    status2Config.preferredStatusBarStyle = .lightContent

    let notification = SwiftMessages()
    SwiftMessages.show(view: error)
    notification.show(config: status2Config, view: status2)
}
```

but just the first message (error) appears.

What is wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the line

```
let notification = SwiftMessages()
```

out of `viewDidAppear` to make it a member variable so that it's retained long enough to display the message.

Comment: @alper Sure it does. Why would you think otherwise? (I'm the author of the library.)